# How to render a jquerymobile page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have an PhoneGap Application which uses JQM. To navigate I use a navbar-widget, which opens the requested page (There are 4 pages).
The first time a page is accessed through this navigation it needs quite a while to show up (depending on the device between 6 and 10 sec). I assume this is because of the rendering process of JQM. Hence this behaviour is not exactly what I want, I wonder if I could render the pages manually the first time the application gets started (i.e. while showing a splash screen). Has anyone done something similar before or has someone an idea of how to start this rendering process manually?

Answer (score 1):

I would presume from your question that you are using several HTML pages through navbar element.

This is your first mistake. I hope this is not a big project for you cause you are going into the world of pain.

First, you can prefetch jQuery Mobile pages, that will improve page change time, read more about it **[here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-cache.html)**. Unfortunately this solution has few problems, mainly sometime it will not work.

My best advice would be to change you app design. Your main navbar pages should be part of a single HTML file, it is also called a multipage template. This is fastest solution but most resource hungry. Also your pages should not be content heavy, it is a main jQuery Mobile app performance killer.

I have to excellent articles for you that will help you build a faster jQuery Mobile app, take a look **[here](http://www.gajotres.net/secrets-of-a-good-jquery-mobile-page-architecture/)** and **[here](http://www.gajotres.net/how-jquery-mobile-page-handling-affects-javascript-executions/)**.

If it is not to late I would advise switching to Sencha Touch. It will take some time to learn it (it has a completely [**different**](http://www.gajotres.net/sencha-touch-vs-jquery-mobile/) approach then jQuery Mobile) but in the end you will have a much faster app. I am telling you this as a jQuery Mobile developer, not a Sencha Touch one.

Comment: Actually I'm using a multipage template. All the pages (jqm pages) exists in the same file. However, it must be possible to force rendering manually, during this time I could display a splash screen or just "loading".